# Simplifying the result formula for depressed Cubic

Tags: algebra-precalculus

After understanding the Cardano's formula for solving the depressed cubic (of the form $x^3+mx=n$, of course), I tried to find the solution of the equation $$x^3+6x=20.$$
After plugging into the formula
$$x=(n/2+\sqrt{ \frac{n^2}{4}+ \frac{m^3}{27} })^{1/3}+(-n/2+\sqrt{ \frac{n^2}{4}+ \frac{m^3}{27} })^{1/3}$$
where $m=6$ and $n=20$, we get
$$x=(10+ \sqrt{108})^{1/3}-(-10+ \sqrt{108})^{1/3}.$$
However, we notice that, without using Cardano's formula, that $x=2$ is the solution for the equation $x^3+6x=20.$
My question is: how does the equation $$x=(10+ \sqrt{108})^{1/3}-(-10+ \sqrt{108})^{1/3}$$ get simplified to $x=2$?

P.S. I understand that it was Niccolo Fontana who first figured out how to solve depressed cubic, to give one the proper credit.

Comment: If you'll stop trying to simplify it, it might not be depressed as much! :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the benefit of hindsight we notice that $10+\sqrt{108}=10+6\sqrt{3}$ and 
$$10+6\sqrt{3}=(1+\sqrt{3})^3.$$
Similarly, 
$$-10+6\sqrt{3}=(-1+\sqrt{3})^3.$$
Take the (real) cube roots and subtract.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. How did you come up with the quantity $ \pm 1 + \sqrt{3}$? Surely you did not think of that quantity of blue, did you?

Comment: More or less yes. If there were going to be  "nice" cube roots they would have to look like $\pm 1+r\sqrt{3}$, where $r$ is rational, because of the root $2$ that you observed. Now it takes little to see that $r=1$ works.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
&\left(10+\sqrt{108}\right)^{1/3}-\left(-10+\sqrt{108}\right)^{1/3}\\
&=\left(10+6\sqrt{3}\right)^{1/3}-\left(-10+6\sqrt{3}\right)^{1/3}\\
&=\left((1+\sqrt{3})^3\right)^{1/3}-\left((\sqrt{3}-1)^3\right)^{1/3}\\
&=(1+\sqrt{3})-(\sqrt{3}-1)\\
&=2
\end{align*}

The formula:
$$(A+B\sqrt{3})^3=A^3+3\sqrt{3}A^2B+9B^2A+3\sqrt{3}B^3$$ is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a^3 = 10+\sqrt{108}=10+6\sqrt{3}, b^3 = -10 + \sqrt{108}=-10+6\sqrt{3}\implies a^3-b^3 = 20 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=(a-b)((a-b)^2 + 3ab)$. Observe that $(ab)^3 = 8 \implies ab = 2\implies (a-b)((a-b)^2 + 6) = 20\implies x^3+6x-20 = 0, x = a-b$. Using synthetic division we have: $x^3+6x-20 = 0\implies (x-2)((x+1)^2 + 9) = 0 \implies x = 2$ as claimed.